# Create outlook rule for emails with a from address which is a distribution list

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-365

Is is possible to create an outlook rule for emails which have a from address which is the address of a mailing list? For example I receive an email with the from address set to `list@company.com`. If I create a rule for messages with `from` set to `list@company.com` outlook realises this is a mailing list and tries to create a rule for messages from the members of this list.

I've managed to do this in the past somehow with older versions of outlook as I have existing rules that work. We're now using Outlook 365 and if I attempt to edit my old rules it converts the from addresses into mailing lists.

Answer (score 0):

According to my research, the option of "with list@company.com in the message header" might be helpful to you. Please try and see if it can meet your needs.